# How to replace string with method value?

Tags: java

I have a String that is coming from an API or stored in my database, and I want to replace all tags with my tags at runtime. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Using `if else` is not efficient, since my model has more than 100 fields.

```
String rawText= "Hello %name% !, Nice to meet you! Your age is %age%."
```

I want replace all `%____%` text with my value stored in my Model.

```
class Person{
     private String name;
     private String age;

     getter...
     setter....
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? ever heard of concatenation?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Are you using Jackson or Gson by any chance?

Comment: Jaction or GSON convert json to java object but its not json. also I am not trying to convert json to java object. finding pattern(%age%) from text is not an issue but getting age from model where public method is getAge().

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. Please answer the question(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the field values by name:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String replaceTags(String rawText) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%(.+?)%").matcher(rawText);
        boolean result = m.find();
        if (result) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            do {
                m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(getField(m.group(1))));
                result = m.find();
            } while (result);
            m.appendTail(sb);
            return sb.toString();
        }
        return rawText.toString();
    }

    private String getField(String name) {
        try {
            return String.valueOf(this.getClass().getDeclaredField(name).get(this));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not read value for field: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/5Ny1bA)

If you're on Java 9, you can simplify `replaceTags()` with a replacement function:

```
public String replaceTags(String rawText) {
    return Pattern.compile("%(.+?)%").matcher(rawText)
            .replaceAll(r -> Matcher.quoteReplacement(getField(r.group(1))));
}
```

If you have a JSON serialization library like Jackson, you can use it to handle the reflection automatically and build a map of values by field name:

```
Map<String, Object> fieldValues = new ObjectMapper()
        .convertValue(this, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Comment: I like this solution and I think using "%(\w+)%" in regular expression can handle empty %%

Answer (score 2):

Using Reflection You can do it with few lines of code :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Main {
public static void main(String arg[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    String rawText= "Hello %name% !, Nice to meet you! Your age is %age%.";
    Field[] fields = Person.class.getFields();

    Person person = new Person("TestName", "TestAge");

    for(Field  field: fields) {
        rawText = rawText.replace("%"+field.getName()+"%", (String)field.get(person));
    }
}
}
```

Just make the fields public in Person class.

Comment: This solution doesn't use regex. Use `String.replace()` instead.

Comment: @Tom It uses a method that expects regex, but the value passed in is plaintext and may in fact be invalid regex.

Comment: What I did can also be done without regex,  plaintext can also be treated as regex. Yeah it can be invalid, but as per java naming conventions[camel case] it should not be invalid.

Comment: @shmosel I just answered with the relevance to the question, I am not seeing any field will be having base64 string, It's just some name, age or whatever a person have as property.

Comment: *plaintext can also be treated as regex.* Not as a rule. `a$` is a valid field name. See what happens if you try replacing it as regex.

Answer (score 1):

you can use replaceAll

```
    String rawText= "Hello %name% !, Nice to meet you! Your age is %age%.";
    rawText = rawText.replaceAll("%name%", "new name");
    rawText = rawText.replaceAll("%age%", "new age");
```

where the new name and new age can come from your model.

Comment: Use `replace()` unless you need regex.

Comment: true replaceAll for regex. here replace should do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why regular string concatenation would not be sufficient here.  Just define a helper method inside `Person` which builds the output string using the properties of a given person:

```
public class Person {
    // ...
    public String getGreeting() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        sb.append("Hello ").append(name).append(", nice to meet you!  Your age is ");
        sb.append(age).append(".");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but my use case don't meet the answer because i don't know what will be the raw text , it could be any text with tags like ..%age%

Comment: @NandanSingh OK...I will leave this post here in case it might be useful to someone else.